# How to set table column as nullable by default

Tags: sql-server

I am using AWS RDS Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4422.0 (X64).
Trying to create test table.

```
create table t1(id int not null, s varchar) on [primary]
```

But `s` column is not null-able.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 't1'

COLUMN_NAME IS_NULLABLE
id  NO
s   NO
(2 rows affected)
```

I expected `s` would be `IS_NULLABLE = yes` because `not null` wasn't set explicitly.
So for now the only one way to set `s` as NULLABLE I have to use

```
create table t1(id int not null, s varchar null) on [primary]
```

So may question is how to force SLQ to set any column to NULLABLE if a column is not set as NOT NULL explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the [`SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187375.aspx) tsql command:

```
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ON;
GO
create table t1(id int not null, s varchar) on [primary]
GO 
-- NULL insert should succeed.
INSERT INTO t1 (id, s) VALUES (1, NULL);
```

Note that for this to work, the [`SET ANSI_DEFAULTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188340.aspx) should be set to off.

Personally, I think that the default behavior is not to be trusted anyway, since you never know if some other member of your team has changed it.
Therefore I recommend setting explicit values for everything, including `NULL / NOT NULL` options.